# Linux watch dog - change the noway out config at runtime

Tags: linux, watchdog

Using the /dev/watchdog seems to only be effective for monitoring another process, as without the CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT option set when compiling the kernel a crash in the monitoring/watchdog process will cause the OS to clean up and close the file. Thus stopping the watch dog.

There are of course many types of crashes and failures that benefit from the no way out option.

If I don't have control over the kernel in use (i.e. I can't change to one configured with the no way out option), is there a way at run-time to switch the behavior of the /dev/watchdog to no way out?

Comment: In your kernel, is the watchdog functionality modularized or builtin? Also, which specific driver are you using? The ones that support "Magic Close" will do what you want without CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT.

Comment: ...by the way -- this looks more like a question about system administration than about programming; it probably would be a better fit on Server Fault.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `nowayout=0` or `nowayout=1` as a module parameter, which will override the value compiled in for `CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT`.

---

In a file such as `/etc/modprobe.d/watchdog.conf`:

```
options softdog nowayout=1
```

...replacing `softdog` with the actual watchdog driver in use, should it be a different one.

---

Alternately, it may be that your kernel has watchdog support compiled in. If that's the case, you can put `<modulename>.<option>=<value>` on the kernel command line in your bootloader configuration, as in:

```
softdog.nowayout=1
```

---

That said, for many drivers this is unnecessary, as those supporting "magic close" will not reset unless the driver writes a `V` character before closing the file, such that inadvertant crashes or shutdowns will not prevent the watchdog from triggering a reboot.

Comment: is `softdog.nowaitout=1` a typo ? Shouldn't it read `nowayout` ?